# Можно ли изменить постоянную ссылку в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ссылки

Можно ли как-то в WP изменить часть постоянной ссылки, которая подчёркнута красным, хотелось бы указать свой путь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В отдельно взятой записи или глобально? Откуда там взялся доктор?  Исправь вопрос пояснив всё это

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у вас есть custom post type. Для него можно сменить slug. Вот тут детально: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/redeclare-change-slug-of-a-plugins-custom-post-type